# Sorting Multi-Dimensional Array Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array variable $data and I am trying to sorting it alphabetically. I am going through a foreach loop and trying to sort of the key.

The array in the middle is not being sorted to match the other arrays. Yelp should be the last one, instead DealerRater is showing last.

I am trying this:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
   ksort($key);
}
```

My $data Array:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Cars.com] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 1
                [rooftop_name] => Norm Reeves Honda - Cerritos
                [name] => Cars.com
                [review_site_id] => 30
                [review_count] => 289
                [review_average] => 4.80
            )

        [Dealer Rater] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 1
                [rooftop_name] => Norm Reeves Honda - Cerritos
                [name] => Dealer Rater
                [review_site_id] => 10
                [review_count] => 1231
                [review_average] => 4.90
            )

        [Google+ Local] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 1
                [rooftop_name] => Norm Reeves Honda - Cerritos
                [name] => Google+ Local
                [review_site_id] => 31
                [review_count] => 556
                [review_average] => 4.80
            )

        [Yelp] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 1
                [rooftop_name] => Norm Reeves Honda - Cerritos
                [name] => Yelp
                [review_site_id] => 29
                [review_count] => 423
                [review_average] => 3.50
            )

    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [Cars.com] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 45
                [rooftop_name] => Leith Volkswagen of Raleigh
                [name] => Cars.com
                [review_site_id] => 30
                [review_count] => 95
                [review_average] => 4.90
            )

        [Google+ Local] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 45
                [rooftop_name] => Leith Volkswagen of Raleigh
                [name] => Google+ Local
                [review_site_id] => 31
                [review_count] => 21
                [review_average] => 4.80
            )

        [Yelp] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 45
                [rooftop_name] => Leith Volkswagen of Raleigh
                [name] => Yelp
                [review_site_id] => 29
                [review_count] => 3
                [review_average] => 1.50
            )

        [Dealer Rater] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 45
                [rooftop_name] => Leith Volkswagen of Raleigh
                [name] => Dealer Rater
                [review_site_id] => 10
                [review_count] => 0
                [review_average] => 0
            )

    )

[56] => Array
    (
        [Cars.com] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 56
                [rooftop_name] => Wilde Jaguar Of Sarasota
                [name] => Cars.com
                [review_site_id] => 30
                [review_count] => 34
                [review_average] => 4.70
            )

        [Dealer Rater] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 56
                [rooftop_name] => Wilde Jaguar Of Sarasota
                [name] => Dealer Rater
                [review_site_id] => 10
                [review_count] => 271
                [review_average] => 4.90
            )

        [Google+ Local] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 56
                [rooftop_name] => Wilde Jaguar Of Sarasota
                [name] => Google+ Local
                [review_site_id] => 31
                [review_count] => 31
                [review_average] => 4.70
            )

        [Yelp] => Array
            (
                [rooftop_id] => 56
                [rooftop_name] => Wilde Jaguar Of Sarasota
                [name] => Yelp
                [review_site_id] => 29
                [review_count] => 1
                [review_average] => 1.00
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Look at related questions

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting the wrong value. Do this:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
   ksort($value);
}
```

`$key` is the index of the main array. `$value` is the array element you want to sort. It'd make more sense if you named your variables more logically, like this:

```
foreach ($data as $index=>$element) {
   ksort($element);
}
```

Or this for short:

```
foreach ($data as $element) {
   ksort($element);
}
```